# Execute jar file on multiple clients

Tags: java, sockets, server, client-server, telegram-bot

i have a telegram bot application that execute jar file in the server by message with path to jar file.

```
public SendMessage startApp(String path, long chatId, int messageId) {
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = run.exec(path);
        check = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        check = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
        p.destroy();
    } finally {
        if (check) {
            sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
            sendMessage.setText("Đã bật app với đường dẫn " + path);
            sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(messageId);
            return sendMessage;
        } else {
            sendMessage.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatId));
            sendMessage.setText("Sai đường dẫn " + path);
            sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(messageId);
            return sendMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

As i know, it only solves problem with client that running app, i want to execute jar file in another clients.
Is it possible if i provide `ip address` of client?
If possible, what i can do?
Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not possible without a custom app/extension on the client machine. Does the jar file really need to be executed on the client PC? That raises all sorts of security issues. Instead, could the same code be built into a website/applet, because you could send a link just fine for the client to click on.

Comment: @sorifiend thank for the answer, my task is run another jar file and check if this running or not (not my application) in another vps server. Of course, my application is running on main server.